# PHP read xml blob from mysql

Tags: php, xml, blob

I have stored an xml file in mySQL using the code below.  I know the DB calls are not parameterized (this will be an non-public tool and will not live on the web).  The create_table function also appears below and the XML file after applying addslashes is written to mySQL as MEDIUMBLOB type.  The challenge is that after searching here and on the web have not been able to find means to successfully read the BLOB object from the database and display the XML.  Note the last block of code where I am able to successfuly read the mySQL record and can see the XML using var_dump (700+ characters) but when I use a simple echo I only see a very small string.  Thanks for the assistance!

```
//Creates Table for per each XML file name encountered
            create_table($servername,$username,$password,$dbname,$tablename,$adminname);

            //Read the contents of the XML file and write it to the table - $tablename
            $xmlContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($pathName));
            //$xmlContent = "test";

            //Write to the table 
            try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (stig_release_id, stig_xml_data, admin_name,stig_xml_filename)
                VALUES ($releaseID, $xmlContent, $adminname, )";

                //stig_xml_filename

                $sql = "insert into `".$tablename."` (`stig_release_id`,`stig_xml_data`,`admin_name`, `stig_xml_filename`) values ('".$releaseID."','".$xmlContent."','".$adminname."','".$aFileName."')";

                $conn->exec($sql);
                echo "<br>... New record created successfully in $tablename ";
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                echo "<br style='color:red'>" . $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                }

            $conn = null;
            $xmlCount ++;

        }

}

function create_table($servername,$username, $password,$dbname,$tablename,$adminname){
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    stig_release_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    stig_xml_filename VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    stig_xml_data MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL, 
    admin_name VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "<br><b>Table $tablename created successfully</b>";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br style='color:red'>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    }

    $conn = null;


}
```

This is a snapshot of phpAdmin showing the data in one of the tables:

[Database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaDD7.png)

```
//Creates Table for per each XML file name encountered
            create_table($servername,$username,$password,$dbname,$tablename,$adminname);

            //Read the contents of the XML file and write it to the table - $tablename
            $xmlContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($pathName));
            //$xmlContent = "test";

            //Write to the table 
            try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (stig_release_id, stig_xml_data, admin_name,stig_xml_filename)
                VALUES ($releaseID, $xmlContent, $adminname, )";//this sql string errors out

                //stig_xml_filename

                $sql = "insert into `".$tablename."` (`stig_release_id`,`stig_xml_data`,`admin_name`, `stig_xml_filename`) values ('".$releaseID."','".$xmlContent."','".$adminname."','".$aFileName."')";

                $conn->exec($sql);
                echo "<br>... New record created successfully in $tablename ";
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                echo "<br style='color:red'>" . $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                }

            $conn = null;
            $xmlCount ++;

        }

}

function create_table($servername,$username, $password,$dbname,$tablename,$adminname){
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    stig_release_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    stig_xml_filename VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    stig_xml_data MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL, 
    admin_name VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "<br><b>Table $tablename created successfully</b>";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br style='color:red'>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    }

    $conn = null;


}

//Creates Table for per each XML file name encountered
            create_table($servername,$username,$password,$dbname,$tablename,$adminname);

            //Read the contents of the XML file and write it to the table - $tablename
            $xmlContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($pathName));
            //$xmlContent = "test";

            //Write to the table 
            try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (stig_release_id, stig_xml_data, admin_name,stig_xml_filename)
                VALUES ($releaseID, $xmlContent, $adminname, )";

                //stig_xml_filename

                $sql = "insert into `".$tablename."` (`stig_release_id`,`stig_xml_data`,`admin_name`, `stig_xml_filename`) values ('".$releaseID."','".$xmlContent."','".$adminname."','".$aFileName."')";

                $conn->exec($sql);
                echo "<br>... New record created successfully in $tablename ";
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                echo "<br style='color:red'>" . $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                }

            $conn = null;
            $xmlCount ++;

        }

}

function create_table($servername,$username, $password,$dbname,$tablename,$adminname){
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    stig_release_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    stig_xml_filename VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    stig_xml_data MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL, 
    admin_name VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "<br><b>Table $tablename created successfully</b>";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br style='color:red'>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    }

    $conn = null;


}
```

This is the code where I have attempted to display the data and the output below.  What is strange is that when I do and array var_dump I can see the XML and able to read the other fields successfully.  However, I am unable to retrieve only one short string vs. the entire XML content.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
//Get XML Data from DB Test

$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "stig_compliance";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$tablename = "uwindows2003dcv6r40stigscap11benchmarkcpedictionary";
$fieldname = "stig_xml_data";

$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = $dbname;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT stig_xml_data  FROM $tablename WHERE id=1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id=1";

echo "<br>SQL = $sql";

if (!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: Query failed to execute: \n";
    echo "Query: " . $sql . "<p>";
    echo "Errno: " . $conn->errno . "<p>";
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error . "<p>";
    return "Error: " . $conn->error;

    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Query Successfully Completed: <p>";
}

$fetchAll = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump ($fetchAll);

$stigfilename = $fetchAll[0]['stig_xml_filename'];
$xmlstring = stripslashes($fetchAll[0]['stig_xml_data']);

echo "<br>STIG File Name = $stigfilename<br>";
echo "<br>STIG XML Data = $xmlstring<br>";


echo "<br> Try using SimpleXMLElement";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
foreach ($xml->stig as $record) {
    echo "<br>STIG Record Data: $record";
    echo '<div class="STIG_record">'."\n";
    echo '<p>'.$record->stig_xml_data.'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$record->stig_xml_filename.'</p>';
    echo '</div><!--end STIG record-->'."\n";
}
```

[Output for code, above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvcou.png)

Comment: So you do read in the blob data from MySQL! For this issue --*However, I am unable to retrieve only one short string vs. the entire XML content.*-- you need to XPath the XML content to parse needed node value (of which you make no mention of by the way). Quite a bit of PHP (being a web dev language) questions on SO is parsing XML documents. Happy searching.

Comment: I always find it extremely weird when people avoid prepared statements. They're not here **only** to make your code "safe". You have an SQL error because you sent values that contained string-content but weren't quoted. With prepared statements that wouldn't have happened. The code wouldn't be so ugly either. Since you're just starting with this - do **yourself** a favor and use prepared statements. I see that many people try to reinvent the wheel with their own database classes, instead of using existing libraries, but I can't understand why you guys avoid prepared statements. Good luck.

Comment: The challenge is not with prepared statements or with parsing of XML.  Per my question var_dump indicates that full xml is present but other methods used to assign and echo variable results in a short string.  I did not remove the comment re. the SQL query failing.   The SQL query to write and read the value both work.